# R, plots layout with proportions

Tags: r, legend, figure

I am looking for a way to put four regions into mine plot, that will have the logic of the matrix below:

```
> matrix(data=c(1,3,2,4),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

cell 1: is going to be the larger Figure. The real plot contains info everywhere so an added legend obstructs more
cell 2: will be containing only the legend of Figure 1
cell 3: Figure 2
cell 4: Figure 3

Ideally I would like the cell 1 to take in height 70% giving only 30 percent for the legend while the three and four share the available height equally.

So far I have found the layout function and I have created some reproducible code

```
layout(matrix(data=c(1,3,2,4),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))
# Figure 1
plot(runif(1000))
#Figure 2 actually is only the legend that does not fit below Figure 1, for my case
plot.new()
legend("bottom",legend="THis is a very big string that will not fit with the Figure above so it has to be below the Figure")
# Figure 3
plot(runif(1000))
# Figure 4
plot(runif(1000))
```

This code creates a Figure with the four regions where unfortunately I can not set the proportions as I need. Even though I can set widths and heights with the layout command these are in effect for the whole row and not individually as I need so.

Are there any recommendations on how I can tweak this code further?

I would like to thank you in advance for your reply
Regards
Alex

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix is not well defined. For the proportions you want, something like this will work (you can play more to get your exact proportions):

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,3,3,1,1,3,3,1,1,4,4,2,2,4,4), nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))
# Figure 1
plot(runif(1000))
#Figure 2 actually is only the legend that does not fit below Figure 1, for my case
plot.new()
legend("bottom",legend="THis is a very big string that will not fit with the Figure above so it has to be below the Figure")
# Figure 3
plot(runif(1000))
# Figure 4
plot(runif(1000))
```

[image]